# Why won't Tensorflow 2.1 recognise my GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.x

I'm trying to setup Tensorflow 2 on a windows machine which I've checked has a Cuda capable GPU (Nvidia Quadro RTX 3000). I've installed the necessary CUDA libraries and SDKs and added to my path (see below):[image].

I've installed tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu via pip. I've checked my setup with the following:

```
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
result = tf.config.list_physical_devices()
print(tf.__version__)
print(result)
print('Built with cuda: ', tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
print('Built with gpu support: ', tf.test.is_built_with_gpu_support())
print('is gpu available: ', tf.test.is_gpu_available())
print('gpus: ', gpus)
```

The output I get however is:

```
2.1.0
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
Built with cuda:  True
Built with gpu support:  True
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-1-601dc453d590>:14: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
is gpu available:  False
gpus:  []
```

Other questions on this issue concern problems setting up tensorflow which doesn't seem to be the case here. Why can't tensorflow still not see my GPU? Is there anything I have missed?

Comment: Tensorflow doesn't support CUDA10.2 for now as far as I remember. Try CUDA10.1

Comment: I installed CUDA10.1 and it worked, thank you very much! If you want to post that as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TensorFlow 2.1` does not support `CUDA 10.2` for now.

You have to use `CUDA 10.1` as written in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements).